# Remapping iTerm 2's shortcut for clear buffer

Tags: iterm2

I want to use command-K to go up a line. At the moment, it's mapped to clear buffer. I see now way to remove it from triggering clear buffer. Is this possible? If so, how. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You can un-assign `⌘K` as the shortcut for *Clear Buffer* by assigning a different key combination (e.g., `^⌥⇧⌘K`) in *System Preferences* → *Keyboard* → *Shortcuts* → *App Shortcuts*:

[image: Screenshot of Keyboard preferences]

The same shortcut can be added via the command line using the `defaults` command:

```
defaults write com.googlecode.iterm2 NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add 'Clear Buffer' '@~$^k';
```

Restart iTerm.app for the new shortcut to take effect.